# Lag in updating UI with databinding due to calling an async method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, xamarin, async-await

In a Xamarin.Forms app I'm binding a boolean `Upvoted` property to an `Image`'s `Source` property (through a converter), to switch between two icons, indicating whether the user has upvoted for a picture or not, I'm sending the `Upvoted` value along with the `UserId` and `ImageId` to  the server, then I update the icon, that causes a little lag for the icon to change

the first (slow) version of my method:

```
private async void OnVoting(ImageVotingModel image)
     {
          if (await SendVote(image)) //is responsible for updating database, it returns true only when the voting is updated successfully
             Images.Single(x => x.id == image.id).UpVoted = !image.UpVoted;
     }
```

and then I changed to this:

```
 private async void OnVoting(ImageVotingModel image)
        {
            if (IsBusy)// it's true when there is a work being done on server
                return;
            Images.Single(x => x.id == image.id).UpVoted = !image.UpVoted; //with data-binding, once the Upvoted change the icon should be updated
            if (!await SendVote(image))
                Images.Single(x => x.id == image.id).UpVoted = !image.UpVoted;

        }
```

the line:

```
Images.Single(x => x.id == image.id).UpVoted = !image.UpVoted;
```

is supposed to update the UI immediately through the databinding:

```
 <Image Source="{Binding UpVoted, Converter={StaticResource boolToImage}}"/>
```

so what I was expecting is that the image will be updated immediately (like when I commented out the code that calls `SendVote` ::

```
private async void OnVoting(ImageVotingModel image)
        {
            if (IsBusy)// it's true when there is a work being done on server
                return;
            Images.Single(x => x.id == image.id).UpVoted = !image.UpVoted; //with data-binding, once the Upvoted change the icon is updated
           // if (!await SendVote(image))
             //   Images.Single(x => x.id == image.id).UpVoted = !image.UpVoted;

        }
```

but the problem still there, the UI lags like it's waiting the server to finish updating its data.

Comment: how are we supposed to know what the commented code looks like when you didn't post it.. also do you understand the difference between sync vs async..?

Comment: Based on your title, it's not working at all, but after reading the question, it's working but it's just lagging.  It's a bit confusing, can you please update the question to properly reflect the issue?

Comment: minimized, modified, please have a look at it again

Answer (score -1):

The important piece of information needed here is what `SendVote` does.  It may or may not block the caller's thread, regardless of whether you call it using `await`.

I'm not certain, but your confusion may come from thinking that `await` by itself causes the `SendVote` method to run on a separate thread.  Rather, the `await` keyword only affects how the remainder of the method is scheduled upon completion of the specified `Task` (`Task<bool>` in your case).